# Working on Topic using JMS Active MQ, but not able to get a desired result

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, jms, message-queue

I am trying an a publisher - subscriber example using ActiveMQ ,

The code for Publisher is as follows

```
package com.topic.one;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.DeliveryMode;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;


public class MyTopicPublisherOne extends Thread {

private static final String TOPIC_NAME = "MyTopic";
private static final String BROKER_URL = "tcp://localhost:61616";
private final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(BROKER_URL);

@Override
public void run() {
    Connection con = null;
    Session session = null;
    Destination dest = null;
    MessageProducer producer = null;
    DateFormat dateFormat = null;        
    try {
        con = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        con.start();
        session = con.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        dest = session.createTopic(TOPIC_NAME);
        producer = session.createProducer(dest);
        producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm:ss.SS a");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            TextMessage msg = session.createTextMessage();
            if (i < 20) {
                msg.setText(i + " MESSAGE : " + dateFormat.format(new Date()));
            } else {
                msg.setText("done");
            }

            producer.send(msg);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try{
            this.closeResource(session, con);
        }catch(JMSException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void closeResource(Session session,Connection con) throws JMSException{
    if(session != null)
        session.close();
    if(con != null)
        con.close();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t = null;
    try {
        t = new MyTopicPublisherOne();
        t.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And the below code is for Subscriber

```
package com.topic.one;


import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.Session;

import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.jms.Topic;
import javax.jms.TopicConnection;
import javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.TopicSession;
import javax.jms.TopicSubscriber;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

public class MyTopicSubscriberOne extends Thread implements MessageListener{

public MyTopicSubscriberOne(String name){
    this.setName(name);
}

private static final String TOPIC_NAME = "MyTopic";
private static final String BROKER_URL = "tcp://localhost:61616";
private static final TopicConnectionFactory connectionFactory =  new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(BROKER_URL);
private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
@Override
public void run(){        
    TopicConnection con = null;
    TopicSession session = null;           
    MessageConsumer consumer = null; 
    TopicSubscriber subscriber = null;
    Topic topic = null;
    try{           
        con = connectionFactory.createTopicConnection();            
        session = con.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        topic = session.createTopic(TOPIC_NAME);
        subscriber = session.createSubscriber(topic);
        subscriber.setMessageListener(this);
        con.start();
        latch.await();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try{
            if(consumer != null)    
                consumer.close();

            if(session != null)
                session.close();

            if(con != null)
                con.close();
        }catch(JMSException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    TextMessage textMessage = null;
    String text = null;
    try {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            text = textMessage.getText();
            if (text != null && text.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
                latch.countDown();
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" - "+text);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String [] args){
    MyTopicSubscriberOne [] threads = null;
    try{
        threads = new MyTopicSubscriberOne[]{
            new MyTopicSubscriberOne("NANCY"),
            new MyTopicSubscriberOne("MIRANDA"),
            new MyTopicSubscriberOne("JESSICA")
        };
        for(MyTopicSubscriberOne t : threads){
            t.start();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

My questing is,

After running subscriber,
my output is

```
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 4 MESSAGE : 9:27:49.28 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 4 MESSAGE : 9:27:49.28 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 4 MESSAGE : 9:27:49.28 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 5 MESSAGE : 9:27:51.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 5 MESSAGE : 9:27:51.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 5 MESSAGE : 9:27:51.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 6 MESSAGE : 9:27:53.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 6 MESSAGE : 9:27:53.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 6 MESSAGE : 9:27:53.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 7 MESSAGE : 9:27:55.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 7 MESSAGE : 9:27:55.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 7 MESSAGE : 9:27:55.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 8 MESSAGE : 9:27:57.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 8 MESSAGE : 9:27:57.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 8 MESSAGE : 9:27:57.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 9 MESSAGE : 9:27:59.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 9 MESSAGE : 9:27:59.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 9 MESSAGE : 9:27:59.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 10 MESSAGE : 9:28:01.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 10 MESSAGE : 9:28:01.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 10 MESSAGE : 9:28:01.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 11 MESSAGE : 9:28:03.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 11 MESSAGE : 9:28:03.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 11 MESSAGE : 9:28:03.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 12 MESSAGE : 9:28:05.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 12 MESSAGE : 9:28:05.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 12 MESSAGE : 9:28:05.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 13 MESSAGE : 9:28:07.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 13 MESSAGE : 9:28:07.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 13 MESSAGE : 9:28:07.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 14 MESSAGE : 9:28:09.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 14 MESSAGE : 9:28:09.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 14 MESSAGE : 9:28:09.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 15 MESSAGE : 9:28:11.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 15 MESSAGE : 9:28:11.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 15 MESSAGE : 9:28:11.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 16 MESSAGE : 9:28:13.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 16 MESSAGE : 9:28:13.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 16 MESSAGE : 9:28:13.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 17 MESSAGE : 9:28:15.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 17 MESSAGE : 9:28:15.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 17 MESSAGE : 9:28:15.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 18 MESSAGE : 9:28:17.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 18 MESSAGE : 9:28:17.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 18 MESSAGE : 9:28:17.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 19 MESSAGE : 9:28:19.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 19 MESSAGE : 9:28:19.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 19 MESSAGE : 9:28:19.36 PM
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - done
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - done
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - done
```

Why my output doesn't prints the Thread Names like Nancy, JESSICA etc ?
Why it prints 'ActiveMQ Session Task-1' as the thread name ?

Also i want to know why the following messages are not printed

```
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 1 MESSAGE : 
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 1 MESSAGE : 
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 1 MESSAGE : 
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 2 MESSAGE :
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 2 MESSAGE :
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 2 MESSAGE :       
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 3 MESSAGE :     
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 3 MESSAGE :
ActiveMQ Session Task-1 - 3 MESSAGE :
```